# The derivative of $\sin(\alpha x)/ \sin(x)$ is continuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $\alpha$ be a real number. Define $f = \sin(\alpha x)/ \sin(x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $\alpha$ at $x = 0.$ How can I prove the derivative of $\sin(\alpha x)/ \sin(x)$ is continuous at $0$? I took the derivative and tried to apply L'Hopital's rule but I kept getting $0/0$ and could not make the argument work... Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Both $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ and its reciprocal are analytic, non-vanishing functions in a neigbourhood of zero, so it is
$$ \alpha\operatorname{sinc}(\alpha x)\frac{1}{\operatorname{sinc}(x)}. $$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}f'(0)=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\alpha h)}{\sin h}-\alpha}h\\=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\alpha h)-\alpha\sin h}{h\sin h}\\=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left[\alpha h-\frac{\alpha^3h^3}{3!}+O(h^5)\right]-\alpha\left[h-\frac{h^3}{3!}+O(h^5)\right]}{h^2}\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac h{\sin h}\\=&~0.\end{align*}$$For $x\ne0,f'(x)$ is given by$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{\sin x}\right)=\frac{\alpha\cos(\alpha x)}{\sin x}-\frac{\cos x\sin(\alpha x)}{\sin^2x}$$The limit at $0$ is given by$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\alpha\sin x\cos(\alpha x)-\cos x\sin(\alpha x)}{\sin^2x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1-\alpha^2)\sin x\sin(\alpha x)}{\sin 2x}=0$$by L'Hopital. Thus the derivative is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative at $0$ is$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\alpha h)}{\sin h}-\alpha}{h}=\alpha\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{1-\tfrac16\alpha^2h^2+o(h^2)}{1-\tfrac16h^2+o(h^2)}-1}{h}=\alpha\lim_{h\to0}(\tfrac16(1-\alpha^2)h+o(h))=0.$$The derivative at some small but nonzero $x$ is$$\begin{align}&\frac{\alpha\cos\alpha x\sin x-\sin\alpha x\cos x}{\sin^2x}\\&\in\frac{\alpha(1-\tfrac12\alpha^2x^2+o(x^2))(x-\tfrac16x^3+o(x^3))-(\alpha x-\tfrac16\alpha^3x^3+o(x^3))(1-\tfrac12x^2+o(x^2))}{x^2+o(x^3)}\\&\in\alpha(1-\alpha^2)(\tfrac13x+o(x)),\end{align}$$which $\to0$ as $x\to0$. Therefore, the derivative is continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score -1):

An elementary proof without l'Hôpital nor Landau's big O notation:
for all $x\neq 0$,
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\frac{\alpha\cos(\alpha x)\sin(x)-\sin(\alpha x)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\\
%
&=\left(\frac{(x-0)}{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}\right)^2\frac{\alpha\cos(\alpha x)\sin(x)-\sin(\alpha x)\cos(x)}{(x-0)^2}.
\end{align*}
By continuity of the square and inverse functions, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{(x-0)}{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{(x-0)}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{\cos(0)}\right)^2=1.
\end{align*}
Let us write:
\begin{align*}
\alpha\cos(\alpha x)\sin(x)-\sin(\alpha x)\cos(x)&=\alpha\big(\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(0)\big)\sin(x)+\alpha\cos(0)\sin(x)\\
&\quad-\sin(\alpha x)\big(\cos(x)-\cos(0)\big)-\sin(\alpha x)\cos(0)
\end{align*}
Notice first that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\alpha\big(\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(0)\big)\sin(x)}{(x-0)^2}&=\alpha\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(0)}{x-0}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}=\alpha(-\alpha\sin(0))\cos(0)=0,\\
%
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)\big(\cos(x)-\cos(0)\big)}{(x-0)^2}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(0)}{x-0}=\alpha\cos(0)(-\sin(0))=0
\end{align*}
by definition of the derivative at 0. Next,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\alpha\cos(0)\sin(x)-\sin(\alpha x)\cos(0)}{(x-0)^2}&=\cos(0)\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\alpha\sin(x)-\sin(\alpha x)}{(x-0)^2}\\
%
&=\cos(0)\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left[\frac{\alpha\big(\sin(x)-\sin(0)\big)}{x-0}-\alpha\cos(0)\right]-\left[\frac{\sin(\alpha x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}-\alpha\cos(0)\right]}{x-0}\\
%
&=\cos(0)\big(-\alpha\sin(0)+\alpha\sin(0)\big)\\
%
&=0
\end{align*}
by definition of the second derivative at 0. As the limit of products is the products of the limits (provided that all limits exist in $\mathbb{R}$), we therefore have established the following:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)&=0.
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{\sin(x)}-\alpha}{x-0}\\
%
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-0}{\sin(x)}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)-\alpha\sin(x)}{(x-0)^2}\\
%
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-0}{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)-\alpha \sin(x)}{(x-0)^2}
\end{align*}
is proved to be 0 as well using the above computations. This shows that $f'(0)=0$ and thus $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$.

**Remark.** The above proof works as well for any function $f(x)=\frac{g(\alpha x)}{g(x)}$ where $g$ is smooth and satisfies $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$.

Comment: This shows that $f$ is continuous at $0$ -- not that its derivative is.

Comment: @JohnColeman This actually shows the difficult part namely finding the value at the point 0 where the denominator cancels. Since when answers have to provide 100% of the details?

Comment: @Nicolas That’s not what the question asks for.

Comment: @Tavish The question asks for continuity at 0 for the derivative. So you differentiate and compare what you get near 0 (what I did not do here) and what you get precisely at 0 (what I did). Should I write 'HINT'?

Comment: If you tried to use this limit directly in computing $f'(0)$ you would get $0/0$.

Comment: @Nicolas Didn’t you compute $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ instead? Where have you stated what $f’(0)$ precisely is?

Comment: @John Coleman & Tavish That's right: I have computed $f(x)-f(0)$ (as $f(0)=0$ by definition). So my last comment was not correct indeed: my argument should have include a division by $x-0$ for the derivative, I apologize!

Comment: @JohnColeman I've taken the time to write it clearly. It is less 'neat' now and uses the second derivative, but the trick is the same. Thanks for your useful comments.